# TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined how i can fix that

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
    function onEdit(e) {
      
      var range = e.range;
      var spreadSheet = e.source;
      var sheetName = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
      var row = range.getRow();  
      var dat = activesheet.getRange(row,1).getValue();
    
      if(dat == "") {
        if(sheetName == 'hi') {
         var new_date = new Date();
         spreadSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new_date).setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss Am/Pm"); 
      }
      }
    }
```

#i got this problem in sheet i want the date add
#but didn't update again if any changes happened in data in the row

Comment: The function requires the event object so you can run it without the trigger unless you supply the event object.

Comment: And it seems your key `#` is broken a bit.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see where you defined variable "activesheet".
Why don't you add a line like,

```
var activesheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
```